# Administrator role capabilities

Tags: capabilities

I need to make that administrator could'nt manage options, but it is not working...

My code:

```
function set_capabilities() {
     $editor = get_role( 'administrator' );
     $editor = remove_cap('manage_options');
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'set_capabilities' );
```

What I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're creating a function and just initializing a local scope variable that you overwrite it.

here is a different approach:

```php
global $wp_roles; // global class wp-includes/capabilities.php
$wp_roles->remove_cap( 'administrator', 'manage_options' );
```

_based on [codex:remove_cap](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_cap)_

Edit:

```php
/**
* Remove capability from admins.
*/
function wpcodex_set_capabilities() {

    // Get the role object.
    $admin = get_role( 'administrator' );
    $admin->remove_cap( 'manage_options' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpcodex_set_capabilities' );
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but not working...

Comment: try my later edit

Comment: I was logged as super admin, so it wasnt working ... now it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 different ways you can do this:

Add either of these code snippets to your child themes functions file.

```
function set_capabilities() {
     $role = get_role( 'administrator' );
     $role = remove_cap('manage_options');
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_capabilities' );
```

Or you could also use this:

```
function set_admin_capabilities(){

global $wp_roles;
$wp_roles->remove_cap( 'administrator', 'manage_options' );
    }
add_action( 'init', 'set_admin_capabilities' );
```